# Bending Label in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am newbie to cocos2d, I am trying to create the effect as if in photoshop but its with CCLabelTTF. The image can describe more about the requirement which I am trying to use. [image: Bending the Label "MARINE"]. I am trying to rotate using the action CCRotate but I am unable to create the same effect.

Please help me to get this effect in cocos2d with CCLabelTTF. As the text "MARINE" can be replaced with any text. I cannot use the CCSprite instead of CCLabelTTF as I would use any text.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating your own font class that is a subclass of CCSprite that allows you to alter the scale and skew? That might be what you need here. Create a bitmap font-type of sprite image library and create a subclass to which you can pass any text string you want and get results similar to the above using image manipulation in the CCSprite class.

I don't think CCLabelTTF can do this as it is not based on images.

Comment: Thank you for your respose @andrewx. Font doesn't matter me that much.  Also I don't want to use the CCSprite class I need to do it with the CCLabelTTF OR bitmap font.

Comment: When you want to do things that are particularly custom, you need to subclass and create your own logic. Why do you *need* to use CCLabelTTF? You are talking about image manipulation, not text manipulation.

Comment: @andewx I want the output for the effect that the text does create, not the effect that image gives by bending.